# How to add a filtered foreign key with a custom validation or something else to solve the following requirement?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the following db design, but I want to know how to restrict the insertion in the table CagesOfCatsAndDogs matching:

> Cat_ID and Dog_ID must have the same Owner_ID that we are adding to
>   the field Owner_ID of the table CagesOfCatsAndDogs.

[image]

Some people told me to do that through triggers, and ok that sounds good, but if someone have an other way or know some best practices to design that great.

Comment: some people are right. But the design looks strange to me, what if someone has 2 cats and one dog ? or 2 dogs and one cat ? or 2 cats and no dog ?

Comment: That is not a problem @GuidoG, Cat_ID and Dog_ID could be nullable fields and the last dog should sleep alone :'(

Comment: so if you have 3 cats than you have 3 records with each time one column wasted. I think a table with AnimalID and AnimalType (cat or dog) would be a better design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**|** Pet type `PET_TYPE_ID` exists.

*Pet type is identified by `PET_TYPE_ID`.*

```
PetType {PET_TYPE_ID}
    KEY {PET_TYPE_ID}
```

**|** Owner `OWNER_ID` exists.

*Owner is identified by `OWNER_ID`.*

```
Owner {OWNER_ID}
  KEY {OWNER_ID}
```

**|** Pet `PET_ID` of pet type `PET_TYPE_ID` is owned by owner `OWNER_ID`.

*Pet is identified by `PET_ID`.*

*Each pet is of exactly one pet type, for each pet type it is possible than more than one pet is of that type.*

*Each pet is owned by exactly one owner, for each owner it is possible that more than one pet is owned by that owner.*

*If a pet is of a pet type, then that pet type must exist.*

*If as pet is owned by an owner, then that owner must exist.*

```
Pet {PET_ID, PET_TYPE_ID, OWNER_ID}

KEY {PET_ID}
KEY {PET_ID, OWNER_ID}  -- superkey, redundant here but needed in SQL
                        -- to be referenced by a FK

FOREIGN KEY {PET_TYPE_ID} REFERENCES PetType {PET_TYPE_ID}
FOREIGN KEY {OWNER_ID}    REFERENCES Owner {OWNER_ID}
```

**|** Cage `CAGE_ID` is owned by owner `OWNER_ID`.

*Each cage is owned by exactly one owner, for each owner it is possible that more than one cage is owned by that owner.*

*If a cage is owned by an owner then that owner must exists.*

```
Cage {CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID}

 KEY {CAGE_ID}
 KEY {CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID}  -- the superkey, redundant here but needed in SQL
                          -- to be referenced by a FK

FOREIGN KEY {OWNER_ID} REFERENCES Owner {OWNER_ID}
```

**|** Pet `PET_ID` owned by owner `OWNER_ID` is located in Cage `CAGE_ID`.

*Each pet is located in exactly one cage, for each cage it is possible that more than one pet is located in that cage.*

*If a pet is located in a cage, then that pet must exist.*

*If a pet is located in a cage, then that cage must exist.*

*If a pet owned by an owner is located in a cage, then that cage is owned by that owner.*

```
PetInCage {PET_ID, CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID}
      KEY {PET_ID}

FOREIGN KEY {PET_ID,  OWNER_ID} REFERENCES Pet  {PET_ID,  OWNER_ID}
FOREIGN KEY {CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID} REFERENCES Cage {CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID}
```

---

Notes:

- Everything is `NOT NULL` here.
- Use `UNIQUE` to create alternate keys `{CAGE_ID, OWNER_ID}` and `{PET_ID, OWNER_ID}`.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be more efficient way to create the mapping table

```
╔════════════════╗
║ Pets           ║
╟──┬─────────────╢
║PK│ID           ║
║  │PET_NAME     ║ e.g. "Sam", "Max", "Lassie"
║FK│PET_TYPE_ID  ║➝Pet_Types.ID
║FK│PET_OWNER_ID ║➝Owners.ID
╚══╧═════════════╝

╔═══════════════╗
║ Pets_Types    ║
╟──┬────────────╢
║PK│ID          ║
║  │NAME        ║ e.g. "Cat", "Dog", "Cow"
╚══╧════════════╝

╔═══════════════╗
║ Owners        ║
╟──┬────────────╢
║PK│ID          ║
║  │NAME        ║ e.g. "Mrs Miller", "Hubert Cumberdate"
╚══╧════════════╝
```

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ Pets_Cage     ║
╟──┬────────────╢
║PK│ID          ║
║FK│PET_ID      ║➝Pets.ID  In case owner have more than 2 pets or have same kind of pets.
║FK│CAGE_ID     ║➝Cages.ID This will allow you to put multiple cats/dogs in same cage
╚══╧════════════╝

╔═══════════════╗
║ Cages         ║
╟──┬────────────╢
║PK│ID          ║
║  │NAME        ║
╚══╧════════════╝
```

Owner table will remain same. Plus you can break down the "Pets" table further to map one pet with multiple owners (that ususally doesn't happen).

Comment: This design looks much more logic to me

Comment: I understood your new model but really I have created this as an example with a real life entities to be more clear but with your design (much more logic for these entities) I have the same doubt. Why the field PET_TYPE_ID in the table "CagesOfCatsAndDogs"? And the main doubt, that could allow inconsistences you agree? because if I add to table CagesOfCatsAndDogs a pet of type 1 and in it own field PET_TYPE_ID a different type of pet I think it's wrong.

Comment: @DeepakPawar thanks, but notice that your model still allowing to put pets of different's owners in the same cage, that's the major problem that I  have.